# I get a 404 not found when I use POST method of $http to request local PHP file

Tags: php, angularjs, post, http-status-code-404

Scenario: 
I have a contact form. when I finished the form, then I click submit, an email with form information will be sent to my email box. 
So, I decede to use POST method of $http in AngularJS to request my local PHP file.

Here is my JS code:

```
var data = {
  name: angular.element("#input-name").val(),
  email: angular.element("#input-email").val(),
  help: angular.element("#input-help").val()
};
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "app/components/start_menu/email.php",
  data: data
})
  .then(function(){
    $scope.showMessage = true;
  })
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

  if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $help = $_POST['help'];

    $message .= "Name: " .$name ."\n";
    $message .= "Email: " .$email ."\n";
    $message .= "Comments: " .$help ."\n";

    mail("hansonchen128@gmail.com", "New User Request", $message);
}
?>
```

I get the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/app/components/start_menu/email.php 404 (Not Found)

(anonymous function)    @   angular.js:10514

sendReq @   angular.js:10333

$get.serverRequest  @   angular.js:10045

processQueue    @   angular.js:14567

(anonymous function)    @   angular.js:14583

$get.Scope.$eval    @   angular.js:15846

$get.Scope.$digest  @   angular.js:15657

$get.Scope.$apply   @   angular.js:15951

(anonymous function)    @   angular.js:23303

jQuery.event.dispatch   @   jquery.js:4435

jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle    @   jquery.js:4
```

The request url is correct, because I can use GET method to request this url. When I use GET method, everything is good, but not for POST method.